# Prefix Creation Aborted

Tags: macos, mac, wine, macos-catalina, prefix

Absolutely *must* get *Windows* version of VisualBoyAdvance running on Mac OS Catalina, sorry I *cannot* accept "download VBA-M" as an answer for what I'm doing, it's complicated.

What I have to do is make a bundle through WineBottler, but this has consistently been a weird and complicated process and I'd like some help on it. When I make the bundle I get the "Prefix Creation Aborted" window and this log:

```
###BOTTLING### default.sh
/Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 39: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin19
Wine.........................: 
WineBottler..................: 4.0.1.1
Wineticks....................: 20210206-next - sha256sum: e08cfb38938b63f34f9b19d59791b79779fdb2c1f636599a54e81332eb3d511b

Environment
PWD..........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
PATH.........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
USER.........................: [REDACTED]
HOME.........................: /Users/[REDACTED]
COMPUTERNAME.................: [REDACTED]
BUNDLERESOURCEPATH...........: /Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources
WINEARCH.....................: win32
WINEPREFIX...................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources
WINEPATH.....................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/usr/lib
SILENT.......................: 
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Bottle
TEMPLATE.....................: 
BOTTLE.......................: /Users/[REDACTED]/Downloads/N1GP_Community_Folder/VBA.app
INSTALLER_URL................: /Users/[REDACTED]/Downloads/N1GP_Community_Folder/VisualBoyAdvance.exe
INSTALLER_IS_ZIPPED..........: 0
INSTALLER_NAME...............: VisualBoyAdvance.exe
INSTALLER_ARGUMENTS..........: 
REMOVE_MONO..................: 
REMOVE_GECKO.................: 
REMOVE_USERS.................: 
REMOVE_INSTALLERS............: 
WINETRICKS_ITEMS.............: arch=32 win7 
DLL_OVERRIDES................: 
EXECUTABLE_PATH..............: winefile
EXECUTABLE_ARGUMENTS.........: 
EXECUTABLE_VERSION...........: 1.0.0
BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT.............: Â© Your Company
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER............: com.yourcompany.yourapp
BUNDLE_CATEGORYTYPE..........: public.app-category.games
BUNDLE_SIGNATURE.............: 
SILENT.......................: 

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,1
      Processor Name: 6-Core Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.6 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 6
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 12 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 16 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 1554.80.3.0.0 (iBridge: 18.16.14346.0.0,0)
      Serial Number (system): [REDACTED]
      Hardware UUID: [REDACTED]
      Activation Lock Status: Enabled

###BOTTLING### Create .app...
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 142: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.

Task returned with status 1.
```

I want to know whats going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WineBottler contains a 32-bit version of Wine. It cannot be used on recent macOS versions. WineBottler is very outdated.

Comment: If you have to run the Windows version, why not just run it in a V<?